# Subgraph (Graph Protocol) not building out of schema correctly

Tags: data-types, typescript, graphs

Doing a quick start tutorial to get back in the subgraph mode and my mapping (even though very simple) is not building. The types will compile, but I cannot deploy it due to it being unable to build.

Error here:

```
ERROR TS2322: Type 'generated/schema/Token | null' is not assignable to type 'generated/schema/Token'.

   token.contentURI = event.params._uri;
   ~~~~~
 in src/mapping.ts(43,3)

ERROR TS2322: Type 'generated/schema/Token | null' is not assignable to type 'generated/schema/Token'.

   token.save();
   ~~~~~
 in src/mapping.ts(44,3)
```

Relevant code here:

```
import {
  TokenURIUpdated as TokenURIUpdatedEvent,
  Transfer as TransferEvent,
  Token as TokenContract
} from "../generated/Token/Token"

import {
  Token, User
} from "../generated/schema"

export function handleTransfer(event: TransferEvent): void {
  // Try to call token from Graph Node, passing it token ID
  let token = Token.load(event.params.tokenId.toString());
  // If it doesn't exist, then we make a token and pass it values given to us by the event (the TransferEvent)
  if (!token) {
    token = new Token(event.params.tokenId.toString());
    token.creator = event.params.to.toHexString();
    token.tokenID = event.params.tokenId;
    token.createdAtTimestamp = event.block.timestamp;

    // Call token contract itself to set token metadata
    let tokenContract = TokenContract.bind(event.address);
    token.contentURI = tokenContract.tokenURI(event.params.tokenId);
    token.metadataURI = tokenContract.tokenMetadataURI(event.params.tokenId);
  }

  // Save the token to the store
  token.owner = event.params.to.toHexString();
  token.save();

  // Does user exist?
  let user = User.load(event.params.to.toHexString());
  // If not, we make a new user
  if (!user) {
    user = new User(event.params.to.toHexString());
    user.save();
  }
}

// Updates contentURI of token then saves it back to store
export function handleTokenURIUpdated(event: TokenURIUpdatedEvent): void {
  let token = Token.load(event.params._tokenId.toString());
  token.contentURI = event.params._uri;
  token.save();
}
```

All other files generated by the Graph CLI automatically upon compile - does anyone have any clue where I could be going wrong? Following the quick start tutorial, works fine when they build it with the same lines of code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the final function with this:

```
export function handleTokenURIUpdated(event: TokenURIUpdatedEvent): void {
  let token = Token.load(event.params._tokenId.toString())
  if (token != null) {
    token.contentURI = event.params._uri
    token.save()
  }
}
```